# differences between capture by reference and by copy in lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using depFunction = std::function<void()>;

class Man
{
public:
    class BankAccount {
    public:
        BankAccount(double b, double d) : balance(b), dept(d) {};
    protected:
        double balance;
        double dept;
    };
    class ID {
    public:
        ID(std::string n, int a, std::string s) : name(n), age(a), sex(s) {};
        double getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    protected:
        std::string name, sex;
        int age;
    };
};

depFunction deposit(Man::ID& myManID) {
    double age = myManID.getAge();
    double* agePointer = &age;
    depFunction theFunc = [=]() {
        std::cout << age << std::endl;
        std::cout << agePointer << std::endl;
    };
    return theFunc;
}

int main() {
    Man::BankAccount myManBankAccount(1000, 0);
    Man::ID myManID("Mohammad", 23, "Male");
    depFunction dep = deposit(myManID);
    dep();

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output is:

```
23
010FFC08
```

In this case, I used *capture by copy* in the lambda expression and everything seems okay; but when I'm trying to *capture by reference* instead of *by copy*:

```
depFunction deposit(Man::ID& myManID) {
    double age = myManID.getAge();
    double* agePointer = &age;
    depFunction theFunc = [&]() {
        std::cout << age << std::endl;
        std::cout << agePointer << std::endl;
    };
    return theFunc;
}
```

the output would be:

```
1.82171e-303
CCCCCCCC
```

I expected the output to be as same as the former case; However, I don't know why it happened. I would be glad to know what's going on!

Comment: You're storing references to objects with automatic storage. (One of them is even a dangling reference to a dangling pointer.) Using those references after the objects' lifetimes have ended is undefined.

Comment: Note that your first version also has undefined behaviour since `agePointer` points to a "dead" object by the time you call it. That the code seems to work is just bad luck.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Is it undefined behavior to convert a `double*` to `void*` for printing after the lifetime has ended? I suspect the real problem is not that the object is dead, but that the storage is gone. I.e. you can't use that `void*` for placement new either, which would be valid when you have a pointer to the storage of a dead object.

Comment: @molbdnilo
Thank you for your answer! However, I don't understand why the second version is working if this is the case???

Comment: Accessing invalid memory (either through dangling references, or pointers) invokes undefined behavior. UB means anything can happen, including your code working like you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age` and `agePointer` are local variables in the function `deposit`. When the lambda `theFunc` captures them by reference, those references are only valid while `theFunc` is used in the same scope as the function `deposit`.

When you return `theFunc` from `deposit`, those references to the local variables are dangling, and so you invoke undefined behavior when you call the lambda which tries to access those references.

When `theFunc` captures by copy, it has its own copies of those local variables, and there's no issues with them dangling when you return the lambda from the function. Note that while the *values* themselves are valid, `agePointer` is a pointer that points to a local variable. Accessing the *pointed at* memory is invalid, since it's pointing to `age` which is out of scope.